# how to find consecutive timestamp and calculate sum in python

Tags: python, datetime, cross-join

I am looking for the sum of sales made by each customer within 24 hours.

For example,

```
id     timestamp            sales
123   2022-10-01 12:50:55   11
124   2022-10-01 22:50:55   11
123   2022-10-01 13:50:55   11
123   2022-10-02 12:50:55   11
123   2022-10-02 13:50:55   11
```

Then
For ```id = 123``, we select

```
1. 
id     timestamp            sales
123   2022-10-01 12:50:55   11
123   2022-10-01 13:50:55   11
123   2022-10-02 12:50:55   11
```

```
Sum = 11+11+11 = 33
```

```
2. 
id     timestamp            sales
123   2022-10-01 13:50:55   11
123   2022-10-02 12:50:55   11
123   2022-10-02 13:50:55   11
```

```
Sum = 11+11+11 = 33
```

```
3. 
id     timestamp            sales
123   2022-10-02 12:50:55   11
123   2022-10-02 13:50:55   11
```

```
Sum = 11+11 = 22
```

```
4.
id     timestamp            sales
123   2022-10-02 13:50:55   11
```

```
Sum = 11
```

We get the result for `id = 123` is

```
id     timestamp            sales   sum
123   2022-10-01 12:50:55   11      33
123   2022-10-01 13:50:55   11      33
123   2022-10-02 12:50:55   11      22
123   2022-10-02 13:50:55   11      11
```

```
For id = 124, we get
```

```
id     timestamp            sales   sum
124   2022-10-01 22:50:55   11      11
```

I know cross join could deal with this problem, but this method is time-costing for big datasets.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` giving it `pd.Groupby(freq="D")` and the `id` column:

```py
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])
df.set_index("timestamp", inplace=True)
newDf = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq="D"), "id"]).sum().reset_index()
newDf
```

The `newDf` would be:

|  | timestamp | id | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-10-01 00:00:00 | 123 | 22 |
| 1 | 2022-10-01 00:00:00 | 124 | 11 |
| 2 | 2022-10-02 00:00:00 | 123 | 22 |

Therfore, by calling `newDf[newDf["id"] == 124]` you will get:

|  | timestamp | id | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-01 00:00:00 | 124 | 11 |

Note that, the time would not be exactly as you mentioned, since 00:00 usually be considered the beginning of the day, and not any other time.